# Node JS read in buffered data

Tags: php, sockets, node.js

For some reason when I send a message to the port and attempt to read it in via a buffer, it always hangs as `socket.on('end')` never seems to be reached. Any ideas?

```
var net = require('net');
var buffer = [];

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        buffer.push(data);
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        try {
            var data = buffer.join("");
            console.log(data);
            socket.end('ok');

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
            return;
        }
    });
});

server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

*Edit: here is the PHP that sends the command...

```
public function sendDaemonCommand($address, $template_id, $params = array()) {

    $port = 3000;
    $command = array('template_id' => $template_id, 'params' => $params);
    $command = json_encode($command);

    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
        $this->logError("Failed to create socket on " . $address . "\n\n" . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n\nCommand:\n\n" . $command . "\n" . $this->functionTraceback());
        return false;
    }

    // Connect to socket
    if (socket_connect($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
        $this->logError("Failed to connect to socket on " . $address . "\n\n" . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n\nCommand:\n\n" . $command. "\n" . $this->functionTraceback());
        socket_close($sock);
        return false;
    }

    // Write command to socket
    if (socket_write($sock, $command) === false) {
        $this->logError("Failed to write command to socket on " . $address . "\n\n" . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n\nCommand:\n\n" . $command. "\n" . $this->functionTraceback());
        socket_close($sock);
        return false;
    }

    // Read back from socket
    if (($out = socket_read($sock, 1024)) !== false) {
        $out = trim($out);
        if ($out == "") {
            $this->logError("No message received back from socket on " . $address . "\n\n" . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n\nCommand:\n\n" . $command. "\n" . $this->functionTraceback());
            socket_close($sock);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->logError("Failed to read from socket on " . $address . "\n\n" . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n\nCommand:\n\n" . $command. "\n" . $this->functionTraceback());
        socket_close($sock);
        return false;
    }

    socket_close($sock);
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: We need to see the client that connects. It's the client who's not ending the connection.

Comment: @fire maybe PHP is waiting for data back before it closes whilst node.js is waiting for the socket to close before it sends data back (`.end("ok")`)

Comment: Yes when I run the PHP it hangs because node isn't reaching the `socket.on('end')` code, but how do I fix this?

Comment: @fire `socket_close($sock)` triggers `on('end')`

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but clearly not as it seems to hang.

Comment: @fire are you sure `socket_read($sock, 1024)` doesn't block until it can read data. Try calling `socket_close` before the read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `allowHalfOpen` to true in `net.createServer` then use `socket_shutdown($sock, 1)` after write and `socket_shutdown($sock, 0)` after read.