# Reading a clients data input in a NodeJS TCP Server

Tags: node.js

Im trying to create a NodeJS TCP Server, that will read to the clients input and then act accordingly.

I'd like to know how I can read the data, so I can set up conditionals to perform process.

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

socket.on('data', function(data) {
    buf = new Buffer(256);
    len = buf.write(data.toString());

    if (buf.toString('utf8', 0, len) === "test"){
        console.log("you typed test");
    }

    console.log(len + " bytes: " + buf.toString('utf8', 0, len));
});
socket.write("Connected to server.\r\n");
});
server.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

I am outputting the value inputted here : 
`console.log(len + " bytes: " + buf.toString('utf8', 0, len));` 
but my if statement above this log, isnt matching the value 'test' when I actually type 'test' in the client terminal window.

Any help is appreciated

-chris

Comment: The data your receive in the `'data'` event is chunked so you need to build the buffer. You can then perform your test on the `'end'` event. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412944/node-js-read-in-buffered-data

Comment: @scriptfromscratch Why not add that as an answer, so it can be accepted if it's correct?

Comment: Purely lack of time @JoachimPileborg. I would have preferred to leave a code sample in my answer but I was having to run out of the office :)

Answer (score 6):

I worked it out using the `toString()` method:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  var response = data.toString().trim();

  if (/disconnect/.test(response)) {
    console.log("Client is diconnecting.");
    socket.end('Disconnecting you now.\r\n');
  } 
});

socket.on('end', function() {
  console.log('client disconnected');
});
```